# Stolon vs CrunchyData for HA Postgresql

Tags: kubernetes, helm, postgresql

I'm using **helm** charts with **kubernetes** and I'm trying to deploy High Availability Postgresql database and found this [article](https://blog.lwolf.org/post/how-to-deploy-ha-postgressql-cluster-on-kubernetes/) mentioning three project that provide HA Postgresql:

**1- [Stolon](https://github.com/sorintlab/stolon)**

**2- [CrunchyData](https://github.com/CrunchyData/crunchy-containers)**

**3- Patroni**

I didn't find helm chart example for Patroni, but I installed both helm charts for Stolon and Crunchy. However, I wasn't able to find the differences between them except in the structure, both use statefulset from kubernetes in order to deploy master service and a number of replicas(ReadOnly slaves),stolon has this proxy service that points to the master service which is like an extra layer, makes the stolon look a little more complex than crunchy.

But what I really need to know is:

1. How the replicas will synchronize with the master? synchronous or
   asynchronous.
2. Whats the failover mechanism provided if any?
3. persistence volumes why is there a volume per pod? How is this
   related to the replication?

Comment: The Patroni helm is in incubator vs stable. helm install incubator/patroni. TG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using stolon for its automatic leader election and fail over handling.
Crunchy Data offers small building blocks so there is a lot of work to do to put them all together while stolon has a ready helm chart.
But I didn't try patroni since stolon worked just fine.